# Cannot find downloaded file after SFTP "get" command

Tags: terminal, fedora, sftp

I am using SFTP to download files from a server. It connects to the server fine and when I enter `ls` it lists all the files I am looking for.

When I get to the: `sftp>`, I enter: `get [FILENAME]`

and then it says:

> `Fetching /directory/FILENAME to FILENAME`
>   `/directory/FILENAME 100%`

then it takes me back to: `sftp>`

I have searched for the file on my computer but I cannot find it. I think the second directory it shows should be the local directory I want the file to be downloaded to right? If so how do I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not specify target path in `get` command (as the second argument), the OpenSSH `sftp` downloads the file to the current working directory. That path is not shown anywhere in the output (only file name is in this case).

The output of `get` is like:

```
Fetching <1st_arg_of_get=remote_path> to <2nd_arg_of_get=local_path_or_filename_only_if_no_2nd_arg>
<1st_argument_of_get=remote_path>  xxx% sizeKB ....
```

So generally, you should find the downloaded file in the same path you have started `sftp` from (= current local working directory). To see the local working directory use command `lpwd` in `sftp`. You can also use `lcd` to change the local working directory.

(I assume your local computer is *nix and the `sftp` is OpenSSH.)

Comment: In most SFTP clients, you can issue the `lpwd` command which will return the client's local working directory.  That should be the calling shell's working directory, but it may not be.  You can also use `lcd` to change the local directory and `lls` to get the local directory's contents.

Comment: @BaconBits Thanks for the comment. I have included this to the answer.

Comment: Additionally, you can usually use `!` in your ftp/sftp client to escape to the shell.  `!pwd` and/or `!ls` would be particularly useful here.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help! I really appreciate it! Everything makes sense now :)